# Simulating electrical inputs to an Arduino and Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, gpio, emulation

I have an Arduino-Raspberry Pi system, with many sensors attached, that I want to try to virtually test (without either physical device) on Travis CI. Are there any extant tools capable of simulating GPIO signals coming in and out of a virtual Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

For example, Raspberry Pi can be emulated using QEMU, but QEMU doesn't support GPIO, so I can't use it as-is.

Comment: Generally speaking , no, not without a custom GPIO driver. However, you can play tricks. The problem with GPIO are all the `IOCTL` calls to set/enable/disable certain channels, if you can wrap your GPIO library with a dummy library that just reads inputs from the next line in a file this would work . `gcc` support wrapping functions see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961774/gnu-gcc-ld-wrapping-a-call-to-symbol-with-caller-and-callee-defined-in-the-sam which would make it a link time thing.